# Plot non numeric data on R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

What I am trying to do is to plot some non numeric data on R.

I have a data frame with the following column names and values

**Vessel ID** P560 P765 P456....

**Fabric** M S M....

**Vessel Use** Storing Cooking Storing....

I want to plot *Storing* vessels which are made of *M* fabric

I tried this:

```
pottery <- read.csv (file="potter.csv", header=TRUE)
class(pottery)
ggplot(data = pottery) +
geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Use=="Storing", y = Fabric=="M"))+
ggtitle("Test") +
labs(y="M Fabric", x = "Storing Use")+
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

And what I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOVoE.jpg)

Any idea how to plot this kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

I think the obvious way to present this data would be as a stacked bar plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Use, fill = Fabric)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.5, color = 'gray40') +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(ID     = paste0('p', sample(100:999, 100, FALSE)),
                 Fabric = sample(c('M', 'S'), 100, TRUE),
                 Use    = sample(c("Storing", "Cooking"), 100, TRUE))

head(df)
#>     ID Fabric     Use
#> 1 p935      M Cooking
#> 2 p778      M Cooking
#> 3 p228      S Cooking
#> 4 p608      M Storing
#> 5 p570      M Cooking
#> 6 p398      S Storing
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks! It worked! Can I change the x,y title in some way?

Comment: @MaryM yes, you can add `+ labs(x = 'x axis label', y = 'y axis label', fill = 'legend label', title = 'plot title')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to show. If it is just the count of the vessel IDs that have fabric M and are used for storage you can do something like the following.

Your example:

```
> set.seed(123)
> 
> df <- data.frame(vessel_id = sample(c("P560", "P765", "P456"), 100, replace = TRUE),
+                  fabric = sample(c("M", "S"), 100, replace = TRUE),
+                  vessel_use = sample(c("Storing","Cooking"), 100, replace = TRUE)
+                  )
> 
> head(df)

vessel_id fabric vessel_use
1      P456      M    Cooking
2      P456      S    Cooking
3      P456      S    Storing
4      P765      M    Storing
5      P456      M    Cooking
6      P765      M    Storing
```

Then you can use:

```
library("data.table")

setDT(df)

plot(df[fabric == "M" & vessel_use == "Storing", table(vessel_id)],
     main = "vessel ID with M fabric and Storing use",
     xlab = "vessel ID",
     ylab = "count")
```

This gives you something like this: [link to imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayvMj.png)

Here you use

1. the library `data.table`, setting the dataframe to datatable and its `dt[i,j,by]` syntax
2. the function `table()` that counts the occurences of items in the vessel ID column of the subset `df[fabric == "M" & vessel_use == "Storing",]`
3. the base R `plot()` function

Comment: Thanks for your answer! At this point I don't mind the ID, I only want to show the correlation between Storing vessels and this kind of fabric. Also my table contains hundrents of vessels so I don't know which pot is for storage or cooking use. That is why I need to plot it

Comment: If you want to use a usage subset of your data only (e.g. "only the vessels that are for storage"), you can easily use ```df[vessel_use == "Storing"]``` and continue working with that.

Comment: I tried the code on your answer and  I got this error: Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': nothing to tabulate

Comment: Can you show the exact code that produced the error?